# In Typescript, how can I get the extract the super type of a constrained generic type parameter?

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to get the super type that a generic type parameter is constrained to?

For instance, if I have a function accepting a constrained generic type:

```js
interface Foo {
   myProp: string;
   optionalProp?: string;
}

function myFoo<F extends Foo>(foo: F) { 
   // How can I extract 'Foo' from F?
   type X = Super<F> // What kind of type alias would result in X being 'Foo'
}
```

Specifically, my use case is that I want to operate on the 'known' (Foo) properties of F, but Typescript defers evaluation of F, which means it also considers the `never` type since `never` is assignable to everything and as a result can't treat `F` as `Foo`, even though it's constrained to it.

To illustrate my point, I would expect `keyof F` to accept values `myProp` and `optionalProp`.

This prevents F from being useful when passed to utility functions that map/filter the type, e.g.

```js
import { OptionalKeysOf } from 'type-fest'

function myUtil<T>(myValue: T, select: OptionalKeysOf<T>) {}
```

The above function could be used, for example, for defining default values for optional properties in `F`... but if I try to use it in `myFoo` by passing `foo` as a parameter, it won't accept `optionalProp` as a value.

So basically, I'd like to find a way to just treat any generic type as it's constrained base type. Is that possible in any way?

Here's a [TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Na5EpN) illustrating the difference. If it would be possible to make `myUtil` work without requiring an explicit `Foo` type annotation, that would answer my question explicitly.

To be honest, I don't understand the usefulness of considering the `never` type as assignable to everything in this way. It just seems to get in the way of a lot of otherwise perfectly useful situations.

I mean, what is the point of a generic type constraint, if the constrained type can't be treated at least as what the type's constrained to be?

If there's no way to extract the super type, then could anyone explain why this level of specificity considering `never` in everything is necessary?

Comment: I don't get what you want to "extract". Why not just write `Foo`?

Comment: "*Typescript defers evaluation of `F`, which means it also considers the `never` type since `never` is assignable to everything and as a result can't treat `F` as `Foo`*" - no, TypeScript does not consider `never` for `F`. It's the conditional mapped type in `OptionalKeysOf` that sometimes returns `never`, and TypeScript cannot figure it out for the generic.

Comment: I doubt very much that `F` contains any information you can use to get `Foo` purely in the type system. TS might decide to widen a *value* of type `F` to `Foo`, but that’s not something you can do in type land.  I still don’t understand why you need it? A playground isn’t sufficient (we can’t ask people to navigate away from SO to see the relevant code)

Comment: @Bergi - Check out my TS Playground link... I want to use `myUtil` without having to cast the type as `Foo`... why should I have to cast it as `Foo` is `F` is constrained as `Foo` already?

As best as I understand it, the reason why `keyof F` won't return `'myProp' | 'optionalProp'` is because F could be assigned `never`.

Comment: I think I need to improve/change my question. I suppose a more specific case would be how can I get `myUtil` to accept `optionalProp` as an arg without having to explicitly cast `foo` as `Foo`.

Also, more broadly, I don't understand why TS can't just treat `F` as a `Foo` in mapped types. I get it has to defer evaluation until `F` is assigned a concrete type, but why not just treat it as `Foo`...?

Comment: Yes, I think you should put the code from playground, and especially the error message, in your question.

Comment: Why are you even using a generic here? `{x: string}` extends `{x?: string}` so an optional prop of a supertype might not be an optional prop of a subtype [as shown here](https://tsplay.dev/Woo8PW). It doesn't seem like what you're asking for would actually help your use case.